# Django column "name" of relation "django_content_type" does not exist

Tags: django, django-models

I keep getting the following error when doing a migration (python manage.py migrate):

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "name" of relation "django_content_type" does not exist
```

I've done the following to try and fix it but without success:

1. I've delete all the migrations files for each model
2. deleted all the records in django_migrations
3. run python manage.py migrate --fake-initial

Running Django 1.8.2.

```
python manage.py showmigrations
admin
 [ ] 0001_initial
auth
 [ ] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [ ] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [ ] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [ ] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [ ] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_remove_content_type_name
hashtags
 [ ] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_hashtagvisit_user
posts
 [ ] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_auto_20150530_0715
sessions
 [ ] 0001_initial
users
 [ ] 0001_initial
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you show your `models.py`?

Comment: Can you show the output of `manage.py showmigrations`? Do you have any data migrations? The complete traceback would help as well.

Comment: thanks for the showmigrations just learned something. I see under contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_remove_content_type_name

Comment: your `fake_initial` did not fake the `remove_content_type` migration which was re-applied (and failed since the column `name` was not there). I gave a more elaborate answer below

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Edit 12/2016**: I'm recommending this as a workaround, more suited for personal projects or local environments and not production environments. Obviously if you care about your migration history this is not the way to go.

Encountered this when upgrading to 1.8 and migrating from MySQL to Postgres.

I can't explain why the error occurs, but I was able to get around it by manually adding the column:

1. Delete all migrations
2. Delete records from `django_migrations`
3. Manually add `name` column:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE django_content_type ADD COLUMN name character varying(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'someName';
   ```
4. Run fake initial: `$ python manage.py migrate --fake-initial`

Comment: This seems like a workable hack, but just adds an unused column to the db table django_content_type. looks like theres a migration in OPs migrations that removes this, and I had this too in a fresh install of django 1.8 and a new project. Why is it looking for this column anyway?

Comment: I'd recommend not doing this; `name` was switched from a column to a property in Django 1.8.

Comment: @FlipperPA how do you suggest getting around the problem? If there is a proper fix, I can't find it.

Comment: @John, I gave the answer to your question below.

Answer (score 86):

I ran into the same problem today, and I would like to add a summary of the problem and how to resolve it:

#### Source of the Problem:

Django 1.8 changed its internal database structures and the column `name` is no longer existing in the data base (see [is taken from the verbose_name attribute of the model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/)).

To adress this, a migration `contenttypes`-`0002_remove_content_type_name` is automatically created.

Usually, all your migrations should have been applied and this should be recorded in the table `django_migrations` and all should be fine.

If you for example did a backup of your database using dumpdata, cleared (flushed) all database content, and loaded the dump with loaddata, your `django_migrations` table remains empty.

Thus, `migrate` tries to apply all migrations again (even though your tables are existing), and it fails when it tries to remove the non-existing column `name`.

You can check whether this situation applies by either checking your `django_migrations` table, or - much more conventient - by running `python manage.py showmigrations`. If your situation looks like

```
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
```

you are fine (or in fact you are having a different problem), in case it looks like this

```
contenttypes
 [ ] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_remove_content_type_name
```

you ran into the situation described above. Please double-check, that your database contains all tables and all colums (except for the changes you wanted to apply with your failed migration).

#### What to do / Step by Step Solution:

So our database structure is ok (except for the changes you wanted to apply with your failed migration), but Django / migrate just does not know about it. So let us do something about it:

1. Tell Django, that all contenttypes migrations have been applied:
   `manage.py migrate --fake contenttypes`
   If you want to double-check, run `showmigrations`.
2. Now let's tell Django that all migrations prior to the one you want to apply have been applied. For this, you need the migration number as shown by `showmigrations`. For example, if your situation looks like

   ```
   my_app
    [ ] 0001_initial
    [ ] 0002_auto_20160616_0713
   ```

   and your `migrate` failed while applying `0002_auto_20160616_0713`, the last successfully applied migration in your database was `0001_initial`. We then enforce the entry in the `django_migrations`-table by
   `python manage.py migrate --fake my_app 0001`
   (remember that the number of migrations is sufficient). `migrate` will automatically fake all other dependent migrations if necessary.
3. Now we can apply the missiong migration, and this time we have to do it for real and not faked! So we run `python manage.py migrate my_app`. This should alter the database as required.

   If your last migration depends on other migrations which have not been faked already, you should fake them beforehand.
4. Double-check and clean-up: Use `showmigrations` again to check whether all migrations mave been applied. If there are open migrations, fake them by using `python manage.py migrate --fake`.

#### Things you should *not* do

- delete all migrations - in a production setting this might just not be applicable because they might contain some work for migrating data which should not be lost.
- manually add the column `name` to contenttypes - it will be removed afterwards when the migration is applied. Ok, it's a working hack, but it does not adress the problem.

#### Things you *should* do

Try to figure out how you got into this situation and find ways to avoid it.

My problem was, that I had different databases for my project (sqlite for fast development testing, local postgres for real world testing, remote postgres for production) and I wanted to copy content from one to an other.

Comment: This is BY FAR the better answer.

Comment: There were two things that got me, one I needed to fake a few before it worked (I just worked back) and I had to restart uwsgi to really make sure the changes were applied.  This answer really helped though

Comment: By far the best answer. You saved my database, thanks

Answer (score 12):

I know that is an old question, but this might help some one.
I was getting this error too. The problem was that **content_types** had a migration called **0002_remove_content_type_name** that remove the column "name".
After remove migration data from table and folder this steps works for me:

```
./manage.py makemigrations myappname
./manage.py migrate myappname
./manage.py migrate --fake contenttypes
```

If you have sure that the rest of your db reflect your migration, you can use:

```
./manage.py migrate --fake
```

See the result with:

```
./manage.py showmigrations
```

After that, all your migrations should be marked and you should be fine

Comment: there is no need to clean the migrations table and re-making the migrations, but your answer pointed me in the right direction, thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem but I was able to solve it by adding this into my migration dependencies:

```
('contenttypes', '0002_remove_content_type_name')
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: worked like a charm! I had this issue while migrating to a specific migration in the past (removing some).

Answer (score 4):

I was getting this error after we decided to remove migrations from version control (git) and create a new database from scratch.

Something that worked for me (although to be honest I'm not sure why) was to run 'makemigrations' for each app.  so, 'python manage.py makemigrations app1', 'python manage.py makemigrations app2', and so on for each Django app.

Finally, I just ran 'python manage.py migrate', crossed my fingers, and it worked.

Any insight into how/why this worked would be helpful.

Comment: @LjubisaLivac haha well...I'm happy to help!

Answer (score 2):

Some part of you code is trying to access the django_content_type table when it dose not exist, leading to a ProgrammingError. A work round would be to wrap that part in a try except.
Sample

```
try:
    seller_content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Seller)
    add_seller_permission = Permission.objects.get(
        codename='add_seller',
        content_type=seller_content_type,
    )
except ProgrammingError:
    add_seller_permission = None
```

You can actually replace add_seller_permission = None with just pass, but the above helps if you are using the value somewhere else, so it remains available at least till the migration is done.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error in a Django 3.2 project while running `makemigrations` (and/or `migrate`) on a fresh database. In this case, the issue was that I had a line that was running *on import* (e.g. at the module or class level) that accessed the ContentTypes, like this:

```
TERM_CONTENT_TYPE = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Term)
```

Since the database hadn't been made during import, this always fails with the error above.

The solution in this scenario is to move any database-interacting like that into a method or other place that does not run during import.

Answer (score 1):

Another variant that worked for me (from a blank database) was:

```
./manage.py makemigrations myappname
./manage.py migrate
```

A variant which DID NOT work was:

```
./manage.py makemigrations myappname
./manage.py migrate myappname
```

Or, rather, the sequence would apparently work the first time, but would not work the second time, complaining then that `django_content_type` did not exist.

The working (first 2-line) variant above seems to be idempotent.

(edited: to remove redundant second line from original 3-line working version)

Answer (score 1):

For me, I ran **makemigrations** for each of my **INSTALLED_APPS** with this command:

```
python manage.py makemigrations compressor
```

change compressor with your INSTALLED_APPS. then successfully migrated with this command:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I had many Alter operations in the same migration file.
I split the migrations file into two files making different migration files for that field that has got the error. Finally, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. How I ended up in this position was like others where i was moving databases from one server to another. What happened is i tried to fix a failed migration by deleting all the migration files. What this really did was delete the 0002_remove_content_type_name.py file as well and that is where this whole issue started for me.

This file lives in the \venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\contenttypes\migrations folder. So it is tied direction to your virtual environment. The server i was copying the database to had its own virtual environment (never copied that) so  it still had the 0002_remove_content_type_name.py file in the folder.

To django this looked like an unapplied migration. And since i scraped my migration table and all the migration files in my test server it always looked for that migration on my production server.

How i fixed this was copied the 0002_remove_content_type_name.py from my production server back to my test server and ran the fake migration. So now ever time i copy my test db to prod, this wont happen.

I also, highly do not recommend copying the database like i am doing as that is what got me in all this trouble in the first place.

The full solution in my case if i did not have a copy of this file already would be as follows:

1. Create a new virtual environment
2. Create a test django project from scratch
3. Copy the 0002_remove_content_type_name.py from the newly created virtual environment to the same location in my current project(\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\contenttypes\migrations)
4. run "python manage.py showmigrations" to ensure it is now listed
5. run "python manage.py contenttypes --fake

Now all future migrations should work as it will be listed in the migrations table again.

Note: If you have the same issue with Auth and Admin, do the same thing with the files. They are in their respective folders in the virtual environment. I believe admin has 3 migrations in total and auth has 11. I noticed these were gone after i fixed my content types issue.

Answer (score 0):

Changing contenttypes migrations is a part of auth module and nobody should change those generated migrations.

Run the following to see of what you have done

```
python manage.py showmigrations
```

You should see some of django's migrations have been modified. This generally happens when migrate command with --fake is accidentally run across all the apps instead of a specific app.

To reset run following,

```
python manage.py migrate --fake auth zero
```

Then you may required to split big migration file into smaller migration files and fake some of those. ref - @Hemanta Adhikari

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after an upgrade to Django 5.0.3 and I created the missing table with :

```
ALTER TABLE django_content_type ADD COLUMN name varchar(100);
```

Now it works

Answer (score -1):

well None of this actually worked for me so i just deleted my database in postgresql and created a new one then ran deleted my previous migrations folder and last did all the migrations all over and it everything works just fine