# Django migrations run_before and reset give same error

Tags: django, migration

I have a project with a custom user model. Because of an unrelated screw up, I had to reset migrations. Since I already had set the custom user once, I didn't think about migrating it separately first again, so of course I got

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: 
Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency 
account.0001_initial on database 'default'.
```

Reading this error literally, it seems like I ought to be able to adjust the sequence and be ok, rather than the more challenging steps laid out for when you try to change to a custom user mid project https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/writing-migrations/#controlling-the-order-of-migrations

However, when I did run_before, I STILL got the same error. Here is that code:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    run_before = [
        ('admin', '0001_initial'),
    ]
```

So I tried a reset: python manage.py migrate admin zero

And I STILL get the same error!

So then I tried:

```
dependencies = [
    ('auth', '0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages'),
    ('admin', '0001_initial'),
]
```

And, you guessed it, same error!

What am I doing wrong, and/or what are my options here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. See Obu's answer: [Django column "name" of relation "django_content_type" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545562/django-column-name-of-relation-django-content-type-does-not-exist?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Note I did have to some tweaking to get my code into condition to use Obu's answer, but it is still the right guide.