# Unable to alter table in a django-postgres application

Tags: django, postgresql

I created 2 django apps in a django project and connected each app to a different postgres schema within the same database. Now I'm unable to alter tables in a 1st app(that is using schema1) using "django migrate". The 2nd django app is working fine and I'm able to alter/add/delete tables in the 2nd app

Getting the following error:
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "Mixture_LCI" does not exist

Comment: Have you tried [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46696518/django-db-utils-programmingerror-relation-bot-trade-does-not-exist)