Cannot use Model in deployment, despite being created
I have a Django app with several apps within.
I have App_A with the settings.py and then App_B where I have created the following models:
from django.db import models
from decimal import Decimal
import re


class Webshop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    compare_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    webshop = models.ForeignKey(Webshop, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products')
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @staticmethod
    def parse_price(price_str):
        # Remove currency and convert to a format suitable for Decimal
        price_str = re.sub(r'[^\d,]', '', price_str).replace(',', '.')
        return Decimal(price_str) if price_str else None

Locally, I am able to get all the products, but once I deploy the app, I cannot get any items. I use the following view to show the products, and locally this is fine, but deployed, it gives me an error, see below.
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Webshop, Product

def webshop_dashboard_view(request):
    # get all products
    products = Product.objects.all()
    print(products)

    return render(request, 'webshop_dashboard.html')

And the error I get is:
Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /webshop-dashboard/webshop_dashboard/
Exception Value: relation "WebshopDashboard_product" does not exist
LINE 1: ...id", "WebshopDashboard_product"."date_added" FROM "WebshopDa.

And here is my migration file from the deployment server:
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Webshop',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Product',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
                ('price', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)),
                ('compare_price', models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, null=True)),
                ('date_added', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('webshop', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='products', to='WebshopDashboard.webshop')),
            ],
        ),
    ]

I have tried to re-create the database and migrations, but I cannot seem to figure out why I get this error. Let me know what else information is needed.
Has anyone got an idea on how to fix this?
Updated with settings.py:
import os
import sys
import dj_database_url
from pathlib import Path
from django.core.management.utils import get_random_secret_key

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/
# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("DJANGO_SECRET_KEY", get_random_secret_key())

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = os.getenv("DEBUG", "False") == "True"


# ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.getenv("ALLOWED_HOSTS", "127.0.0.1,localhost").split(",")


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django_plotly_dash.apps.DjangoPlotlyDashConfig',
    'SpotOnAI',
    'SpotOn',
    'WebshopDashboard',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'login_history',

]

X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'SpotOn.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'SpotOn.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'SpotOnAI/templates'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'SpotOn/templates'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'WebshopDashboard/templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'SpotOn.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases
DEVELOPMENT_MODE = os.getenv("DEVELOPMENT_MODE", "False") == "True"
if DEVELOPMENT_MODE:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'SpotDB',
            'USER': 'postgres',
            'PASSWORD': 'root',
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
            'PORT': '5432',
        }
    }
elif len(sys.argv) > 0 and sys.argv[1] != 'collectstatic':
    if os.getenv("DATABASE_URL", None) is None:
        raise Exception("DATABASE_URL environment variable not defined")
    DATABASES = {
        "default": dj_database_url.parse(os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL")),
    }


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
# USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "SpotOn/static"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "SpotOnAI/static"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "WebshopDashboard/static"),
    # os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    # '/var/www/static/',
]
#
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
# STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitencoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

MEDIA_URL = 'media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'SpotOnAI/static/media/'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'SpotOn/static/media/'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'WebshopDashboard/static/media/'),
]

print(f"BASE_DIR: {BASE_DIR}")
for path in STATICFILES_DIRS:
    print(f"Static Dir: {path}")

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/platform/'
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'

LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS = (
    r'^password_reset/$',
    r'^password_reset/done/$',
    r'^reset/([0-9A-Za-z]+)/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$',
    r'^reset/done/$',
)

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'


Even when manually trying to insert into the table using the Django CLI I also get the error.
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError:
 relation "WebshopDashboard_webshop" 
does not exist LINE 1: INSERT INTO 
"WebshopDashboard_webshop" ("name")
 VALUES ('Exa...


Django migrations doesn't move data inside database. The objects you have locally doesn't exist in deployment server db. You have to create these product db from admin or any other relevant form. Then it will work. Does your db exist? Show us settings.py.

Updated with my settings.py. I don't think I quite understand how that works, I can see in my admin as well that they exist, but cannot access in the admin either. But everything else works fine. The main app is the SpotOn app with the settings.py file. You are saying that it is empty and therefore showing an error? Wouldn't it just return "nothing"?

Ok so even when manually trying to insert into the table using the Django CLI I also get the error.
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "WebshopDashboard_webshop" does not exist LINE 1: INSERT INTO "WebshopDashboard_webshop" ("name") VALUES ('Exa...
So it's something to do with the naming?

Try changing webshop = models.ForeignKey(Webshop, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products') field name to something like product_webshop.

Did you include a webshop field value in product. Frist add a webshop to db. Only then you can add products to db. That's because your foringnkey is required.

Look here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46697898/13861187  , did you run your migrations?

Using the fake and zero worked, thanks @Pycm, I don't quite know why? So essentially I just removed all migrations files, ran makemigrations and migrate and then did the fake zero stuff from the link, and it works.
