# Django ProgrammingError: relation already exists after a migration created in the Django source code?

Tags: python, django

I recently checked out the master branch of a project, and there were model changes not yet reflected in a migration:

```
(venv) Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:lucy-web kurtpeek$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auditlog, auth, contenttypes, lucy_web, oauth2_provider, otp_static, otp_totp, sessions, two_factor
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
  Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

Following the instructions, I ran `makemigrations` to create them:

```
(venv) Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:lucy-web kurtpeek$ python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'auth':
  venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/migrations/0009_auto_20180425_1129.py
    - Alter field email on user
Migrations for 'lucy_web':
  lucy_web/migrations/0146_auto_20180425_1129.py
    - Alter field description on sessiontype
    - Alter field short_description on sessiontype
```

Interestingly, the `0009_auto_20180425_1129.py` migration was created in the `venv` containing Django's source code (version 1.11.9), which I don't believe anyone on our team changed. Here is this migration:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.11.9 on 2018-04-25 18:29
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0008_alter_user_username_max_length'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='user',
            name='email',
            field=models.EmailField(blank=True, max_length=254, unique=True, verbose_name='email address'),
        ),
    ]
```

It seems 'innocent enough', but when I try to migrate, I get the following `ProgrammingError`:

```
(venv) Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:lucy-web kurtpeek$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auditlog, auth, contenttypes, lucy_web, oauth2_provider, otp_static, otp_totp, sessions, two_factor
Running migrations:
  Applying auth.0009_auto_20180425_1129...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_user_email_1c89df09_uniq" already exists
```

Some of the answers at [django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29830928/django-db-utils-programmingerror-relation-already-exists) seem to be pretty drastic, like deleting all migrations or using the command option [`--fake`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-fake), without providing an explanation of what fundamentally is causing the error.

Any idea how to address this error?

Comment: `makemigrations` shouldn't generate migrations in the `django.contrib.auth` app. You should try to figure out what code in your project is causing this migration to be created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the `auth_user_email_1c89df09_uniq` relation is actually a Constraint (so not data). I managed to migrate by simply dropping/deleting this constraint in pgAdmin, and similarly for the `auth_user_email_1c89df09_like` index (for which a `ProgrammingError` popped up after that).

After this, I was able to migrate:

```
(venv) Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:lucy-web kurtpeek$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auditlog, auth, contenttypes, lucy_web, oauth2_provider, otp_static, otp_totp, sessions, two_factor
Running migrations:
  Applying auth.0009_auto_20180425_1129... OK
  Applying lucy_web.0146_auto_20180425_1129... OK
```

and the constraint and index have been put back into the `auth_user` table:

[image]

Comment: I'm facing the same issue , last migrations worked but suddenly giving this error, Does this solution have any side effect on data?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the culprit was

```
User._meta.get_field("email")._unique = True
```

somewhere in the .py files.

After deleting the line, `makemigrations` stopped creating migration file in `auth` folder, while keeping the `uniq` constraint that was created by that line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will work:

### NOTE: All data in this field will be lost

After running the last migrations, you have this file `0009_auto_20180425_1129.py`
which is waiting for a migrate... If you have not this file anymore, re run `makemigrations` to have one last migration file waiting for `migrate`.

Go trough that file, in your case `0009_auto_20180425_1129.py`, and inside
`operations`

> I suppose you don't have any data in db

add these lines:

```
migrations.RemoveField(
    model_name='user',
    name='email',
),
migrations.AddField(
    model_name='user',
    name='email',
    field=models.EmailField(blank=True, max_length=254, unique=True, verbose_name='email address'   
),
```

> feel free to comment what you get after

Comment: If there's any important data in the db, then removing the email field and recreating it is not a good recommendation.

Comment: There is no data in db as far as I know

Answer (score 0):

After searching for several solutions, I have found one without data loss based on Lemayzeur's suggestion:

```
STORED_DATA = {}

def store_data(apps, schema_editor):
    User = apps.get_model('users', 'User')
    for user in User.objects.all():
        STORED_DATA[user.id] = user.email


def restore_data(apps, schema_editor):
    User = apps.get_model('users', 'User')
    for key, value in STORED_DATA.items():
        user = User.objects.get(id=key)
        user.email = value
        user.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ...
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(store_data, restore_data),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='user',
            name='email',
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='user',
            name='email',
            field=models.EmailField(
                blank=True,
                max_length=254,
                unique=True,
                verbose_name='email address',
            )
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(restore_data, store_data),
    ]
```