# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "organisation_id" of relation "notification_notification" already exists - Django on Heroku Deployment

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I seem to be getting the following error when I am deploying to Heroku, i've tried to do --fake but it breaks the application and gives a 500 error when you sign up as it does not have an organisation id which is used as a UID.

Any tips on what i can do to stop this happening?

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, blog, chat, contenttypes, customform, integration, licence, location, maintenance, member, notification, organisation, registry, report, risk, sessions, sites, socialaccount
Running migrations:
  Applying notification.0010_auto_20210429_0032...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.DuplicateColumn: column "organisation_id" of relation "notification_notification" already exists
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 243, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 104, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_field(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 487, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 142, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "organisation_id" of relation "notification_notification" already exists
```

Comment: there can be multiple scenarios,  And your question is duplicate, already asked here , this might help.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29830928/django-db-utils-programmingerror-relation-already-exists

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29830928/django-db-utils-programmingerror-relation-already-exists)